# Can I make git create two files for merging (mine & theirs) instead of one

Tags: git

If I end up in more complicated conflict during a rebase or other merge situation, I'd create a "mine" and "theirs" files and make a visual diff with my IDE. Then I would start manually fixing the differences until the files become "equal" and I would copy over the changes to the conflicting file and `git add` it, instead of reading and deleting `<<<<< HEAD >>>>>>>` and `<<<<< current commit >>>>>` sections.

Is there a way to automate the part with creating "mine" and "theirs" files? I just want two files with two distinctive names in the same dir, instead of having to checkout them based on commit versions on my own.

Comment: run [git mergetool](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/merging-with-a-gui/)

Comment: The only thing worth noting is configuration of those utilities, especially on Windows platform. I experienced some problems with spaces in the paths of the utilities, so it's better install those utils to the directories w/o spaces in their names

Comment: BTW, [here's tutorial] for using vimdiff as a 3-way merge tool, if you prefer vim. Perhaps you may configure your favourite IDE to be used as a merge tool too.

Comment: Instead of doing this manually, configure git mergetool and git difftool to use your preferred diff GUI. If your IDE (or whatever GUI diff tool you prefer) is not supported by git you can still launch your GUI tool by writing a shell script or .bat file to pass the appropriate command line arguments

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question as asked, you want [`git checkout-index --stage=`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout-index.html).  Stage 1 is the merge base, the version where the two histories diverged. Stage 2 is yours, stage 3 is theirs.  You can `git checkout-index --stage=all myfile` and it'll print the names it invented for each, e.g.

```
$ git checkout-index --stage=all file.txt
.merge_file_a01172 .merge_file_b01172 .merge_file_c01172        file.txt
```

Having the original around for comparison can be good.

Comment: This is awesome. I never would have guessed by the description of ``checkout-index`` that you could do this. The docs say it copies files from index to working directory. But files in conflict are technically in working directory, right?

Comment: The index usually lists some particular content id for every tracked path, but when you've got a merge conflict, by definition nobody yet knows what content belongs -- so the index lists the id's for all three, the original and both changed versions.  Git treats "files" as a derived and only marginally-useful concept, what matters is the association of pathname and content .

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
git mergetool
```

does exactly what you want. All you have to do is configure the merge tool you want to use (see `man git-mergetool` for the details).

It has built-in support for `kdiff3`, `vimdiff` (in three different modes) and other nice tools and you can extend it to use your IDE as a merge tool.